# How can I change value of a member of an object called pages.total? PHP

Tags: php, pagination

I've got this object, and i want change pages.total

```
JPagination Object
(
[limitstart] => 15
[limit] => 5
[total] => 16
[_viewall] => 
[_errors] => Array
    (
    )

[pages.total] => 4
[pages.current] => 4
[pages.start] => 1
[pages.stop] => 4
)
```

how can I achieve it? Thanks

Comment: Just adding that this seems a hack at best... not the right thing to do things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the property is public

`$object->{'pages.total'} = 'value';`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with JPagination, so I can't tell if it's a private or public property you are tryin to change, but normally you can just do

```
$ob->total = 10;
```

If it's a private property you need to change it from within the object with

```
$this->total = 10;
```

Comment: i my case it looks like `$this->pagination->???', atually `{'pages.total'}` worked, but thank you anyway =)

Comment: Sorry, I read too fast, thought you wanted total, not pages.total :)